# I have a document in Document DB , I want to add a new item in array , how to do this?

Tags: azure, nosql, azure-cosmosdb

My Collection is having this type of document.

```
{
        "id": "65f7a7e9-dc99-4c3a-b9ed-6291a8986343",
        "Username": "akgupta@xpirit.com",
        "Password": "somepassword",
        "FullName": "Abhishek Gupta",
        "DateCreated": "2018-02-18T02:20:50.36367Z",
        "Type": "User",
        "WishList": [
            "18a67f77-5b1b-42f9-8361-bf481fe3a341",
            "3baf9376-1e7f-43af-bd15-0fb317edd95f",
            " << Add New Item HEre  >>"

        ]
    }
```

I simply want to add one more guid in WishList Array of id .

What is the efficient way to do this rather then updating whole document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the DocumentDB API, you could use a stored procedure to accomplish atomically adding a single item to the array. Stored procedures run within a transaction on the server. Here's a sample that implements something similar to the MongoDB 'update' command:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-js-server/blob/master/samples/stored-procedures/update.js

Indeed, there are lots of fun samples here:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-js-server

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're using the DocumentDB (SQL) API. That being the case: there is no "update" command or query syntax. Rather, you have to read your document, update it yourself (e.g. modifying your JSON array), and replace the document.

The only way to avoid this type of modification would be to move your array elements to separate documents that you would need to link somehow (like with an id in the separate wishlist document, referencing your primary document's id, `65f7a7e9-dc99-4c3a-b9ed-6291a8986343` in your example).

Note: If you're using the MongoDB API, then you can use the native MongoDB `update()` command, such as:

```
db.coll.update( {username:"akgupta@xpirit.com"},
 { $push: { WishList: "NewWishListId" } })
```